# Customising letters using Raphael.JS

Tags: svg, raphael

We are facing a problem in plotting the letters using Raphael.JS (that finally renders the structure in SVG).

It is required to skew the letters with different angles. We are able to give the skew effect to the complete shape. But the requirement is to skew the letters partially along its length. Please refer the image for better understanding:

[image]

Any help would really be very helpful.

Comment: You'd have to draw each letter individually as a post-transformed path.

Comment: Hey Robert, Thanks for a reply. Can you please suggest any fiddle code that illustrates the post-transformed path? It would be really helpful. Thanks Again!

Comment: Download an SVG editor such as Adobe Illustrator and use it to draw the letter you want.

Comment: Is there any way in Raphael JS to design custom text alphabets?

Comment: Sure, draw each line of each letter as a path.